# Laravel 5 - Write to vendor directory

Tags: laravel-5

Laravel 5 crashed after working for a while. Here's the error:

> file_put_contents(/Library/WebServer/Documents/project/vendor/services.json):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied
>
> *in Filesystem.php line 74*

I wonder why it's trying to write to the vendor directory?

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 18):

Try this artisan command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: wow, i dont know what happened but it worked! although i was setting up Form Facade when i encountered this issue.

Answer (score 9):

**(See update below!)**

Some storage files used for caching were moved to a different location for Laravel v5.0.15.

Affected files:

- services.json
- compiled.php
- routes.php

To quote one of the devs:

> It makes more sense in vendor. This makes it more clear that the file
>   is very specifically tied to the installed dependencies.

For more information and a discussion regarding the changes, see [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/cfa7fcb60fd60b3870606c910559e67186a7a8a8).

**Update**: The maintainers changed this behavior after some discussion.

As of v5.1, all three files will be written to `bootstrap/cache`. If you're on v5.0.*, read on:

The vendor directory will not be written to unless it is actually writable.

Additionally, the method `useStoragePathForOptimizations(bool)` was added to Illuminate\Foundation\App and can be called from bootstrap/app.php. This sets the property `$useStoragePathForOptimizations` and determines whether the storage directory should be used for optimizations.

See the following two commits for more information:

- [Only use vendor if it is writable](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/49e91aeabba71e16e88b175e1e0b62a6e8d506c9)
- [Allow forcing of storage directory for opts](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/419d3f485ce7946cace4325ef19a30e1d5543951)

Comment: @ajay23romu, you have two options: 1) Upgrade to Laravel 5.1 which uses the `bootstrap/cache` directory to store cache files. Make sure this directory is writable. Or 2) Edit `bootstrap/app.php` and add this line: `$app->useStoragePathForOptimizations(true);` Then make sure the directory `storage/framework` is writable. However, it's recommended to upgrade to Laravel 5.1 which is a "Long Term Support" release.