# Should vendor folder be writable in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, file-permissions

I am confused about files and folders permissions in Laravel.

The docs for 5.0 says:

> Laravel may require some permissions to be configured: folders within
>   **storage and vendor** require write access by the web server.

But 5.1 docs state something different:

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions.
>   Directories within the **storage and the bootstrap/cache** directories
>   should be writable by your web server. If you are using the Homestead
>   virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.

Did something change in Composer handling since Laravel 5.1 or is it just innacurate docs?

Comment: have you seen this, it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028718/laravel-5-write-to-vendor-directory

Comment: I have never set permission on vendor folder as from lv4 to lv5.1, I guess composer handles the permission for vendor. However I always set permission for storage and cache folder and in lv5.1 bootstrap folder